# Modifying Modules path in yii framework

Tags: yii, yii-modules

I am new to yii framework. I have built Category Moudles using gii tool and I have to enter following URL

```
http://localhost:8080/myadminpanel/index.php/category/category/create
```

Here, one category is modules ID and another is Controller ID. How can I made following URL

```
http://localhost:8080/myadminpanel/index.php/category/create
```

Comment: Could you clarify? You want `CreateController`, or rather make a shorter url with `category` controller in `category` controller and `create action`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know where to define [routes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url):

```
'rules' => array(
    'category/create' => '/category/category/create' // For the "create" action
    'category/<action:w\+>' => '/category/category/<action>' // For all category routes
)
```